solana-lldb cannot start due to inability to find libpython3.8.so.1.0
I am new-ish to solana. I am on an Ubuntu 22 virtual machine. I am trying to use solana-lldb alongside solana-ledger-tool program run -l ~/test-ledger -e debugger ~/dev/program/build/program.so so that I can use the debugging tools on a program called by solana-test-validator. However, I am unable to start solana-lldb (installed with the ~/.cache/solana directory). I get the following:
/home/gigachad/.cache/solana/v1.41/platform-tools/llvm/bin/lldb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/gigachad/.cache/solana/v1.41/platform-tools/llvm/bin/lldb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have python3.10 installed systemwide in /usr/bin, and it worth noting I had previously installed CERN's ROOT: CERN ROOT Install. These environment variables make it seem like the ROOT installation kinda hijacked some global configuration for python, and maybe that's why I cannot start solana-lldb.
gigachad@ubuntu22dev405:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/gigachad/root_install/lib
gigachad@ubuntu22dev405:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/gigachad/root_install/lib

For what it's worth, this a fairly new VM, and I also cannot start regular lldb for reasons that seem related to python.
gigachad@ubuntu22dev405:~$ lldb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lldb.embedded_interpreter'
(lldb) 

A final detail is that sudo find / -name "libpython3.8.so*" turns up nothing, so I might not even have the library solana-lldb is looking for.
Any ideas on what I can do? Thank you very much.

I assume solana must have tried to install python 3.8 and failed, because sudo apt install python3.8 cannot locate python3.8. I added another apt repository and installed it and now solana-lldb seems to work...same issue with lldb but not concerned with it at the moment
